# Flutter-webrtc package

Tags: flutter, webrtc, p2p

how to connect two users using flutter webrtc package for a p2p voice call?

I have read about how webrtc works, signaling and how STUN works. I tried to use sip_ua package also but was not able to wrap my head around that how to connect two users. I have been trying for 4 days to implement voice calls using flutter-webrtc package in my application. It will be a great help if someone helps me with how to solve this problem.

Comment: checkout this demo example, might help you https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc-demo

Comment: did you figure it out? im facing the same problem.

Comment: For another example you can look at the code of the simple_peer library https://pub.dev/packages/simple_peer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Check IP of the machine in Windows.
**2)** Run the flutter web-rtc-server on your local machine.
**3)** Fo to the folder change the IP in the config file to local IP
\flutter-webrtc-server>.\bin\server-windows-i386.exe.
**4)** Connect ur mobiles on the same Wi-Fi.
**5)** Enter the server IP, i.e your local IP (on the P2P demo of flutter-webrtc-demo).
**6)** Enter and you will see your mobiles with ID try calling the ID.